# Bound for operator norm in terms of operator spectrum

Tags: normed-spaces

It is a known result that
$$\lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert \leq \sqrt{\rho(A^TA)} $$

Is there a way to bound $\lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert $ using spectrum of $A$ only (not $A^TA$).

Ultimately, 
I am trying to express $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert^t $$ 
in terms of spectrum of A.

I also tried with diagonalization of $A$ into $P^{-1}DP$

Then $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \lvert\lvert A \rvert\rvert^t = \lim_{t\to\infty} \lvert\lvert P^{-1}DP \rvert\rvert^t$$

and I got struck .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because there are nonzero $A$ with spectrum $\{0\}$.  Consider e.g. the matrix 
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$

EDIT:  On $\ell^2$, consider the operator $A$ corresponding to the matrix with diagonal blocks
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr},\ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr},\ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}, \ldots $$
Again the spectrum is just $\{0\}$, but for all $t$ we have $\|A^t\| = 1$.
So no condition on the spectrum can guarantee $\|A^t\| \to 0$.

Comment: Under what condition on the spectrum of $A$ will $\lvert \lvert A^t \rvert \rvert \to 0$ for $t \to \infty$ ?